# Bat file location check

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to run a series of batch files (that are part of a program called DeepFaceLab) and i basically can't run any of them on my Windows 7 x64 laptop because, for some reason, the first attempt to set the batch file location fails.
Basically every bat file in the program calls a specific file "setenv.bat" to set directories but for some reason it isn't working.

I already tried adding/changing some lines (like `CHDIR`) to fix the problem but to no avail.

Here's one of the bat files that calls setenv.bat and the setenv.bat file itself.

Here's the first part of clear workspace.bat

```
@echo off
echo Press space if you want to delete content in workspace folder
pause
call _internal\setenv.bat
mkdir "%WORKSPACE%" 2>nul
rmdir "%WORKSPACE%\data_src" /s /q 2>nul
mkdir "%WORKSPACE%\data_src" 2>nul
```

And here's the first part of setenv.bat

```
SET DP0=%~dp0
SET DP0=%DP0:~0,-1%

rem overriding windows user/local environment
SET LOCALENV_DIR=%DP0%\_local_env
SET TMP=%LOCALENV_DIR%\_tmp
SET TEMP=%LOCALENV_DIR%\_tmp
SET HOME=%LOCALENV_DIR%\userprofile
SET HOMEPATH=%LOCALENV_DIR%\userprofile
SET USERPROFILE=%LOCALENV_DIR%\userprofile
SET LOCALAPPDATA=%LOCALENV_DIR%\localappdata
SET APPDATA=%LOCALENV_DIR%\userroaming

SET PYTHON_PATH=%DP0%\python-3.6.8
```

If i run clear `workspace.bat` without `admin privileges`, nothing happens (cmd opens and closes).

If i run clear workspace.bat as admin, three directories are created inside `C:/` (`data_src`, `data_dst`, model) and the bat file still doesn't work ending with an error `"the system cannot find the path specified"`.

I have two drives (`C:/` and `F:/`) and every bat file is inside the F:/DeepfaceLab folder and every folder made in C:/ is already in F:/ but since the locations are not set correctly, it cannot find them.

This is driving me crazy as i have already tried everything i know..... any idea how to make everything work on my `F:/` drive?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: What's in `%workspace%`? I can't see, whether or how it was defined.

Comment: It seems that any of those variables might be an environment variable where the `.bat` was originally located. Try look up for the declaration of those variables as for instance `%WORKSPACE%`. If any declaration cannot be found for specifically one variable then, run the `set` command in a windows command prompt to find its declaration. Do the same (`set`) in the original device where those `.bat` where running and If you find one of those variables that is not in the result of your `set` statement then you will find the cause of the error. You can redirect output and use `fc` to compare them.

Comment: Where do we can find the original `src` of `.bat`? On GitHub I only see `.py` files for DeepFaceLab repo.